# The build was cancelled because another Xamarin operation is running. Please try again in a moment

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can't find any solution to this problem.

I had built my project in Release mode. When I changed to Debug mode and tried to rebuild the project, I got this error. And I KEEP getting this error no matter what I do.

I cleaned the project. No joy.
Restarted VS2019. No joy.
Deleted the bin and obj folders. No joy.

Switched back to Release mode. No joy.

The boss is waiting for this project and I can't build it because of this stupid unspecified error.

"...Another Xamarin operation is running..."

WHAT OPERATION???!!! How can I cancel that operation?

I rebooted the computer. No joy.

I own the paid version of Visual Studio Professional and this is not ok!!

Edit: I opened another version of the same project. This built ok.

Reopened the problem project and did not get the error.

Just wasted 2 hours on this

Comment: Have you try to close visual studio and open project again then clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my post. Went as far as rebooting the PC. Nothing would work until I loaded another version of the project, built it, then reloaded the problem project and the problem didn't show up again. Very frustrating.

Comment: @Alan did you figure out what was the rot cause? this has been driving me crazy and happening more frequently

Comment: @melspring I haven't found out the cause, but my workaround of opening another project, building it, then re-opening this one, seems to make the problem go away, at least until it happens again. I don't yet know exactly what triggers it. But at least it is not holding me up any more.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A workaround is :

- Unload the Android project
- Clean the solution
- Reload the android project and restore it as Startup project

Now you can clean the solution and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it to work with only unloading/reloading the Android project, and didn't need to clean the solution.

Comment: This also works for me. It's faster than opening other projects. Just Unload and Reload

Comment: Unload and Reload worked for me without clean,

Comment: Wasted half an hour because of this error before I came to this answer. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Just Unload and Reload worked for me. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Unload the given project
Reload the given project
Clean the given project
Build

Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from restarting you may also need to delete bin and obj folders.

Comment: I mentioned that in the third line of my post. Deleted the bin and obj folders. No joy.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but only on Android and not on UWP.
Edit: I opened another version of the same project on Android. This built not ok.
Reopened the problem project and did not get the error, so, problem solved.
Lots of thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I started having this recently -- I use VS for Win connected to Mac to do the build for iOS project.

Let's face it, it's always wonky.  But this got real bad today -- tried restarting VS, rebooting Mac, deleting bin/obj, etc.

Finally comment from OP made me think of something I didn't try -- shut down vs, delete the .vs folder, the bin/obj, and restart VS.  I hate to delete the .vs cuz it resets stuff, including "reloading" my Android project, which I'm not currently working on.

Well, to early to say, but it worked once.

Comment: update: worked again for me...  I'm running 16.9.4